# In Editor, how to replicate Entry's Completed event behavior?

Tags: xamarin.forms

The completed event of an Entry is fired when the return key is pressed. I need the same behavior in the Editor as well. Can anyone give me some examples of how to do this?

The default implementation for Editor only trigger the completed event when,

```
iOS (Unfocusing the editor or pressing "Done" triggers the event).
Android / Windows Phone (Unfocusing the Editor triggers the event).
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/editor#completed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,you can use event `Completed` of `Editor to achieve this.

`Editor` exposes two events:

- [TextChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.inputview.textchanged?view=xamarin-forms) – raised when the text changes in the editor.
  Provides the text before and after the change.
- [Completed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.editor.completed?view=xamarin-forms) – raised when the user has ended input by pressing the
  return key on the keyboard.

The `Completed` event is used to react to the completion of an interaction with an `Editor`. `Completed` is raised when the user ends input with a field by entering the return key on the keyboard (or by pressing the Tab key on UWP). The handler for the event is a generic event handler, taking the sender and `EventArgs`:

```
void EditorCompleted (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var text = ((Editor)sender).Text; // sender is cast to an Editor to enable reading the `Text` property of the view.
}
```

The completed event can be subscribed to in code and XAML:

In XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
x:Class="TextSample.EditorPage"
Title="Editor Demo">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Padding="5,10">
            <Editor Completed="EditorCompleted" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</Contentpage>
```

and C#:

```
public partial class EditorPage : ContentPage
{
    public EditorPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        var layout = new StackLayout { Padding = new Thickness(5,10) };
        this.Content = layout;
        var editor = new Editor ();
        editor.Completed += EditorCompleted;
        layout.Children.Add(editor);
    }
}
```

For more, check:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/editor#events-and-interactivity

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work as the default behavior is "iOS (Unfocusing the editor or pressing "Done" triggers the event). Android / Windows Phone (Unfocusing the Editor triggers the event)". I need it to trigger when Return key is pressed like in Entry but I also need to use Editor to achieve this.

Comment: Since the `Editor` control is used to accept multi-line input, while the `Entry` is used for single-line text input`, So that's the reason for it. And that's the default design of the two controls.